cv2.face.LBPHFaceRcognizer.create()___AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'face'
I am trying to use
cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer.create()

but this error appears after I press enter =
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\gagan\anaconda3\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1948, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\gagan\Desktop\FaceRecognition\students_attendence\train.py", line 49, in train_classifier
    clf = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer.create()
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'cv2.face' has no attribute 'LBPHFaceRecognizer'


I have done the following things to resolve it

Reinstall packages by these commands in the administrator

pip uninstall opencv-python
pip uninstall opencv-contrib-python
pip install opencv-contrib-python

but still get that error only
twist, when I install the same package in PyCharm terminal under that directory it is showing this error
`pip install opencv-contrib-python
Collecting opencv-contrib-python
  Using cached opencv_contrib_python-4.9.0.80-cp37-abi3-win_amd64.whl.metadata (20 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.21.2 in c:\users\gagan\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from opencv-contrib-python) (1.24.3)
Using cached opencv_contrib_python-4.9.0.80-cp37-abi3-win_amd64.whl (45.3 MB)
Installing collected packages: opencv-contrib-python
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Users\\gagan\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\cv2\\cv2.pyd'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.`





pip install opencv-contrib-python --user

Try to installed 3.4.8.29 version for the both opencv and opencv-contrib but they were not installed, I still have an error

If anybody is capable to answer please answer me, I am really bogged down here.
Can anyone help me overcome this problem?

you forgot letter e after R in LBPHFaceRecognizer - but if it can't find face then maybe you created file cv2.py and it imports your file instead of module opencv. it may need to rename your file. You can also check import cv2 and cv2.__file__ to see what file you import

always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback. It will be also more readable in question, and more people can see it - so more people may help.

After correction I got this error =
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\gagan\anaconda3\Lib\tkinter_init_.py", line 1948, in call
return self.func(*args)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\gagan\Desktop\FaceRecognition\students_attendence\train.py", line 49, in train_classifier
clf = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer.create()
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'cv2.face' has no attribute 'LBPHFaceRecognizer'

I think I saw questions about similar problems - so maybe you can find them. Maybe you use older version and it is in different place. Or maybe they only change name. You can use print( dir(cv2.face) ) to see all methods and variables in module cv2.face. Code print( cv2.__version__ ) shows me 4.8.1 (on LInux) and I can use cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer.create() with dot but also cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create() with _ instead of dot

The same question has been posted under #face-recognition tag just two days prior to your one. So, I can advise to try the following:
import cv2.face
...
recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer.create()

